# What causes xcode Swift error "Build input file cannot be found: ... OptimizationProfiles/myproj.profdata"

Tags: swift, xcode, bridging-header

After importing to my Swift project a .c and .h files, I now get error:

> error: Build input file cannot be found:
> '/Users/me/project/OptimizationProfiles/myProject.profdata'

Project built just fine before importing.

What I've tried...
Restarted Mac and Xcode, and did realclean beforehand.  Still same error.

If Bridging header is empty, gets error.
If I add
#include "my.h"
to Bridging header, it gets error.

If I start from new, empty Xcode project, import works okay and no build errors.

Comment: posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586340/adding-an-objective-c-file-into-a-swift-project-breaks-compilation-with-build-i/75598264#75598264