# Adding an Objective-C file into a Swift project breaks compilation with "Build input file cannot be found" error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, bridging-header

I have an existing Swift project (UIKit), Xcode 14.2. I'm trying to add Objective-C code to it, creating `.m` and `.h` files. The moment I try to add it, Xcode asks me to create the bridging header (an empty one) which is created and registered in build settings correctly.

My .h file:

```
#ifndef TestObjC2_h
#define TestObjC2_h


#endif /* TestObjC2_h */
```

My .m file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestObjC2.h"
```

My bringing header file is empty.

When I try to build it, getting the following error:

> error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/.../mycoolproject/OptimizationProfiles/mycoolproject.profdata'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'mycoolproject' from project 'mycoolproject')

Creating the same files in a new Swift project has no issue and compiles fine.

What did I miss?

Comment: The bridging header file should contains the Objective-C interfaces you want to expose to swift . So add « #import "TestObjc2.h" » .

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't help, unfortunately, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you created a new target for your project ? May be you forgot to include some files in it ? (mycoolproject.profdata) or is it created by a specific build script that is not in your target ?

Comment: old target, just added .m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting `CLANG_USE_OPTIMIZATION_PROFILE` was on and disabling it (set to NO) fixes the issue.

In a new project this settings by default is set to NO.